# How to convert this list to a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I need to convert this list:

```
data = ['city', 'Paris, France\nserver-ip', '52.41.152.51']
```

To a dictionary that will look like this:

```
{"city": ["Paris, France"], "nserver-ip": '52.41.152.51'}
```

How can I do that?
Because later on, I'll need to change the value in "city" to other city and country.

Comment: `d = {data[0]: data[1].split()[0:2], data[1].split()[2]: data[2]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confronted this as a multistep problem I'll explain each step here is the solution:

```
data = ['city', 'Paris, France\nserver-ip', '52.41.152.51']
data[1:2]=data[1].split("\n")
data[1]=data[1].split(",")
b = dict(zip(data[0::2], data[1::2]))
```

Firstline is the input data.

Then you split element 1 by the newline character and put the two resulting strings into index 1 and index 2, respectively

Then you turn the `"Paris, France"` string into a list of length two by splitting by a comma.

Finally you zip it all up into a dicitonary.